# Why does math.h define pi, pi/2, 2/pi but not 2*pi?

Tags: c, math.h

This is a really simple question: Why are there [predefined constants](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Mathematical-Constants.html) for pi, pi/2, pi/4, 1/pi and 2/pi but not for 2*pi? Is there a deeper reason behind it?

This question is not about the whole [pi vs tau debate](http://tauday.com). I am wondering if there is a technical reason for implementing certain constants but not others. I can think of two possibilities:

1. Avoiding rounding errors.
2. Avoiding runtime divisions which might be more expensive.

Comment: What would you want to use `2*pi` for? Most trigonometric functions, for example, "repeat" after `2*pi` (have a translational symmetry of `2*pi`). (More formally, for example, `sin(a) = sin(b)` if `a = b (mod 2*pi)`.) This makes it useless to add or subtract `2*pi` to or from numbers you use as arguments to these functions.

Comment: PI, HALF_PI ok, but what is name of 2/pi constant?

Comment: @MvanGeest There are so many use cases. How about normal distributions, fast Fourier transforms, Cauchy's integrals to start with?

Comment: Why didn't they also define `3*pi`, `12*pi`, and `-4*pi`? This question is asking for a discussion that has no definitive answer unless one of the original authors of `math.h` happens to stop by to answer it. Sorry, but voting to close as not constructive; the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) specifically mentions discussion and speculation type questions as being inappropriate for the design here.

Comment: @hanno: There may be *many* use cases, but as I tried to demonstrate, *probably* less than for the other constants. Whether that or something else was the reason for the decision will, as Ken White remarks, remain uncertain until the original authors chime in ;)

Comment: I disagree with you. There are people who have heated discussions about tau (=2*pi) vs pi. My intention was *not* to start this discussion here all over again. However, I still hope there might be a simple answer to my original question. Maybe multiplying pi by 2 gives the exact answer within floating point precision whereas the other constants would give an error at the last digit?

Comment: @Ken: or one of the authors has answered it elsewhere, and someone can find that answer and refer to it. I really don't get why people think standard rationale questions are unanswerable -- the meetings are (somewhat) minuted.

Comment: Of course you disagree; if you agreed, you wouldn't have posted the question in the first place. :-) My close vote was based on my opinion of the question's being proper or not, and I don't feel it is for the reasons I stated. I was polite enough to explain why (which there was no obligation to provide). Maybe multiplying `pi` by other numbers that give "the exact answer within floating point precision" should have been defined as well; maybe the decision was made just because no one saw the need to define `2*pi`. Who knows? And who really cares? If you need it, define it.

Comment: I care because I type this constant approximately 100 times a day.

Comment: May not be about tau vs pi, but thanks for that link, I am definitely using tau from now on!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just my guess.

I suppose that these constants are related to the implementations of different functions in the math library:

```
ck@c:~/Codes/ref/glibc/math$ grep PI *.c
s_cacos.c:  __real__ res = (double) M_PI_2 - __real__ y;
s_cacosf.c:  __real__ res = (float) M_PI_2 - __real__ y;
s_cacosh.c:                    ? M_PI - M_PI_4 : M_PI_4)
...
s_clogf.c:      __imag__ result = signbit (__real__ x) ? M_PI : 0.0;
s_clogl.c:      __imag__ result = signbit (__real__ x) ? M_PIl : 0.0;
ck@c:~/Codes/ref/glibc/math$
```

`M_PI`, `M_PI_2`, and `M_PI_4` show up quite often but there's no `2.0 * M_PI`.  So to Hanno's original question, I think MvanGeest is right --- 2π is just not that useful, at least in implementing `libm`.

Now about `M_PI_2` and `M_PI_4`, their existences are well justified.  The [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Mathematical-Constants.html) of the GNU C library suggests that "these constants come from the Unix98 standard and were also available in 4.4BSD".  Compilers were not that smart back at that time.  Typing `M_PI/4` instead of `M_PI_4` may cause an unnecessary division.  Although modern compilers can optimize that away (gcc uses mpfr since 2008 so even rounding is done correctly), using numeric constants is still a more portable way to write high performance code.

Answer (score 4):

Is 2*M_PI so hard to write?

Seriously though, once upon a time, when people worried about simple compilers that might not do constant folding and division was prohibitively expensive, it actually made sense to have a constant PI/2 rather than risk a runtime division.  In our modern world, one would probably just define M_PI and call it a day, but the other variants live on for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Wouldn't it always give you exactly the same result on platforms with base-2 floating point numbers (i.e., all the platforms we care about)?  (i.e., it would be `M_PI` with 1 added to the exponent)

Comment: Be careful not to confuse things: M_2_PI is defined as 2/pi.

Comment: @stevejessop: multiplication by 2 is exact (barring overflow, which clearly doesn't happen here)

Comment: @Dietrich: yeah, I think I'm being stupid.

Comment: (Note that division by two is also exact; M_PI_2 isn't buying any accuracy either.)

Comment: Less hard to write than M_2_PI :-)

Comment: Well, tau is easier to write.

Comment: @stephen-canon -- multiplication by 2 of a transcendental number, expressed with finite precision representation, does not give exact answer.
Hence, the case for having the practically useful constant of tau=2*pi defined somewhere with full precision, stands.

Comment: @JerzyDziewierz The operations of multiplying by two and rounding a real number to a fixed-width binary floating-point type commute (so long as no overflow or underflow occurs). Thus, having a constant defined does not change anything.